# When is it appropriate to set a request-scoped variable in a JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl, scope, lexical-scope, dynamic-scope

In my experience, it is rarely/never necessary to set `scope="request"` on an EL variable.

For example, I have a page that, given an `item` parameter, constructs a URL specific to that item based on its properties. This page is included in any page that needs to render a link to an item.

## (A) With request-scoped variables

#### itemLink.jsp

```
<%-- Accepts a parameter named 'item' --%>
<c:set var="urlTemplate" value="${param['item'].urlTemplate}" />
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${empty urlTemplate}">
    <c:set var="itemUrl" scope="request" value="/missingProductUrl.jsp"/>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:url var="itemUrl" scope="request" value="${urlTemplate}">
      <c:param name="id" value="${param['item'].id}"/>
    </c:url>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

#### otherPage.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="itemLink.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="item" value="${currentItem}"/>
</jsp:include>

<%-- 'itemUrl' has request scope --%>
<a href="${itemUrl}">Item Link</a>
```

## (B) Without request-scoped variables

#### itemLink.jsp

```
<%-- Accepts a parameter named 'item' --%>
<c:set var="urlTemplate" value="${param['item'].urlTemplate}" />
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${empty urlTemplate}">
    <c:set var="itemUrl" value="/missingProductUrl.jsp"/>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:url var="itemUrl" value="${urlTemplate}">
      <c:param name="id" value="${param['item'].id}"/>
    </c:url>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<c:out value="${itemUrl}"/>
```

#### otherPage.jsp

```
<c:set var="itemUrl">
  <jsp:include page="itemLink.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="item" value="${currentItem}"/>
  </jsp:include>
</c:set>

<%-- 'itemUrl' has page scope --%>
<a href="${itemUrl}">Item Link</a>
```

Is there any reason to use **(A)** over **(B)**? My answer is no, with the following justifications:

- With **(A)**, you need to remember that any other page processed during the same request will see `itemUrl`, and so you should avoid name collisions. It also makes tracing the source of EL variables more difficult, as there's no way to find where a request-scoped variable is set except to search through all pages that are processed during the same request.
- With **(B)**, none of this is an issue because variables only ever have page scope.

**EDIT:**

Perhaps there's a better solution than **(B)**:

## (C) Using a static include

#### itemLink.jspf

```
<%-- Accepts a parameter named 'item' --%>
<c:set var="urlTemplate" value="${param['item'].urlTemplate}" />
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${empty urlTemplate}">
    <c:set var="itemUrl" value="/missingProductUrl.jsp"/>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:url var="itemUrl" value="${urlTemplate}">
      <c:param name="id" value="${param['item'].id}"/>
    </c:url>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

#### otherPage.jsp

```
<c:set var="item" value="${currentItem}"/>
<%@ include page="itemLink.jsp" %>

<%-- 'itemUrl' has page scope --%>
<a href="${itemUrl}">Item Link</a>
```

It's still the case that neither alternative, **(B)** nor **(C)**, requires the use of a request-scoped variable. Is there some reason for using request scope that I've missed?

Answer (score 4):

This section you presented

```
<c:set var="itemUrl">
  <jsp:include page="itemLink.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="item" value="${currentItem}"/>
  </jsp:include>
</c:set>
```

would work only if the itemLink.jsp has only the value for itemUrl and nothing else (No additional html content) But hardly is that a case.

Consider a case where you have a Car object in the request scope in your one.jsp and a link in this page takes you to a two.jsp which needs this same Car object.

Then

```
<c:set var="myCar" value="${requestScope.car}" scope="request"/>
```

would do the job. This would be impossible with method(B).

**update:**
As to why it would not be possible by method(B): In your snippet jsp:include includes the response of the JSP (a text) and then that is set to itemUrl. What if you needed to assign a complex object (non textual, like Car or an ArrayList ) to a request scoped attribute ? A JSP response is *typically* a html text.

Just putting forward an alternative, why not render this way ?

```
<%-- Accepts a parameter named 'item' --%>
<c:set var="urlTemplate" value="${param['item'].urlTemplate}" />
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${empty urlTemplate}">
    <a href value="/missingProductUrl.jsp"/>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:url var="itemUrl" scope="request" value="${urlTemplate}">
      <c:param name="id" value="${param['item'].id}"/>
    </c:url>
    <c:out value="${itemUrl}"/>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

```
<jsp:include page="itemLink.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="item" value="${currentItem}"/>
</jsp:include>
```

All said, I have hardly had situations where  `c:set` was needed. Normally setting of any scoped attributes is done by the servlet/controller. A JSP would just get a scoped attribute and show it. If JSPs were setting scoped attributes, it would be pretty hard to maintain. And it would be better to limit the using of `c:set` to only setting page scoped attributes.

Comment: While I agree that your suggestion would work for that specific case, on other pages I may be using that URL in different ways, not just for a link. And I agree that c:set should only be used to set page-scoped attributes... that's my point in creating this article.